# How to format datagridview content in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i was trying to make my datagridview to manipulate the data just like the image below, but sad to note that i cannot find a way on how to do it.

Please help.

I want my datagridview to be like this:
[image: Customer Transaction]

And this is my database as the source data:
[image: Customer Transaction Database]

Comment: Each column has a `DefaultCellStyle` property of type `DataGridViewCellStyle`, which has a `Format` property. You can assign any format string to it that you can pass to a `ToString` method, e.g. "f2" or "n2" for numbers.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to calculate the balance column? Is the Amount column stored as a string or a numerical type?

Comment: What i was trying say was, after executing a SELECT Statement in the sql database, i want to make the data to the datagridview to appear like the image above. is this possible? i want to split the column in the datagridview into two columns for payment and billing.

Comment: yes...you got it..it is stored as decimal(18,2)..can you help me with it..?